# Convert ArcGis X,Y to lat long python

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

I see a lot of stackoverflow answers asking to convert lat long to X Y, but not the other way round..

I have an excel file of the following format:

```
X Coordinate Y Coordinates
35792.56615 32315.91604
35782.0137  32316.97136
32247.58292 34611.3582
29794.38944 31444.90679
15504.94824 34412.15373
```

Can anyone guide me on how I would be able to convert these representations into lat long coords using python? I have the following additional information if needed:

```
Projected Coordinate System:    SVY21
Projection: Transverse_Mercator
False_Easting:  28001.64200000
False_Northing: 38744.57200000
Central_Meridian:   103.83333333
Scale_Factor:   1.00000000
Latitude_Of_Origin: 1.36666667
Linear Unit:    Meter
```

Is there something in the ArcPy package that allows me to do this?

I'm not familiar with ArcGIS at all.

Comment: It can probably be done by http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/coordinates/ .

Comment: hey @DovGrobgeld thanks for your reply! just to clarify (sorry I'm not familiar at all with ArcGIS) in this case, it would be calling the method c = SkyCoord(X, Y, frame=SVY21, unit='deg') right?

Comment: Just be pragmatic. If you manage to do a round trip between the two coordinate systems, then it is probably ok. Also, you can use the "answers asking to convert lat long to X Y" as further validation that you did the correct conversion.

Comment: @DovGrobgeld sorry I don't understand, I tried doing was I said above, it gives a "Coordinate frame SVY21 not in allowed values"

Comment: Ok. I checked it out a bit more, and it seems that I was misleading you. Apparently astropy does not recognize the SVY21 projection. But a quick search on google for "SVY21 python" shows the following library https://github.com/cgcai/SVY21 .

Comment: Do you have access to ArcGIS (and therefore the ArcPy module)?

Comment: I think this question may have been better researched/asked at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Hello @Erica, Dov, I'm facing the same problem. No I dont have access to arcgis, but if arcpy is freeware I can download it. is there any way to go about this? the library dov gave is highly inaccurate..

Comment: ArcPy is not freeware and requires ArcMap install to function.